# In Master to slave UART Communication, Slave have to respond only for the authorized master

Tags: authentication, uart, master-slave

I have two devices(Master and Slave), Communication between the device is UART protocol. When ever master send commands to slave then slave will respond. When ever slave get a request then slave will respond to master. If somebody sniffed the channel and get the transmitted data(master to slave) then he can send the same request to slave, slave also will respond for unauthorized master. so that my slave is misused by unauthorized master. I should avoid this. **How can i make my slave to respond to only authorized master**. If any command is sent from unauthorized master then slave should not respond.

Awaiting for your reply.

Comment: Have you considered [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption)?

Comment: You are describing a classic "man in the middle" attack, which is typically solved by *authenticating* the message.  The message *authentication* is required to confirm the sender and that the message has not been tampered (aka *message integrity*).

Comment: When authentication is used, during the key exchange the key may be identified by middleman.